# Stripe billing class not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I have added the Stripe library to my composer.json file, ran all commands just to check... update, dump-autoload etc.

In my classmap file the library is shown:

```
'Stripe\\Account' => $vendorDir . '/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Account.php',
```

and so on...

In my app folder i have my classes folder etc:

```
app
  motivate
    Billing
      BillingInterface.php
      StripeBilling.php
```

In my StripeBilling file I reference Stripe like so:

```
<?php

namespace Motivate\Billing;

class StripeBilling implements BillingInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
  }
```

This throws the error:

```
Class 'Motivate\Billing\Stripe' not found
```

So my next thought was:

```
use \Stripe as Stripe;
```

Which returns class Stripe not found.

Where is this going wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#intro):

> To use your API key, you need only call \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey()
>   with your key. The PHP library will automatically send this key in
>   each request.

So, just try using `use \Stripe\Stripe as Stripe;` instead.

Comment: Correct! Nearly there but you solved it for me. Thansks.